# internet has been intermittently cutting off

Tags: networking, router, dns, ssl, ping

So since last week, my internet has been intermittently cutting off. And it wouldn't completely cut off, rather all SSL sites would give me SSL errors, and everything else just wouldn't work. I thought nothing of it at first, but then it really started to bug me. I started opening terminal and pinging google until I saw responses, and that's when the interesting stuff happened.

```
▶ ping google.com
PING google.com (129.129.129.129) 56(84) bytes of data.
//terminal hangs at this point
```

My DNS servers (currently set to my ISPs. Haven't got round to changing them.) returned 129.129.129.129... Some weird random, but strangely satisfying IP address. [Looking it up](http://www.ip-tracker.org/locator/ip-lookup.php?ip=129.129.129.129), it's just a standard IP from Switzerland.

It doesn't respond to pings, nmap fails to show anything. It's not even up.

Okay, so maybe it was just an edge case. Next time it happens let's try it with yahoo.

```
▶ ping yahoo.com          
PING yahoo.com (129.129.129.129) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

Okay now it is getting weird. What is actually going on.

I've also noticed that when the internet comes back, or just before, the pings start returning this:

```
From gateway (192.168.1.1) icmp_seq=4 Destination Net Unreachable
From gateway (192.168.1.1) icmp_seq=5 Destination Net Unreachable
From gateway (192.168.1.1) icmp_seq=6 Destination Net Unreachable
```

I have to stop the ping and start it again and it returns to normal.

This is bare weird.

Comment: Have you tested this on multiple devices? If it is happening only on one device, it is possible that your device is infected with malware that poisons its DNS cache.

Comment: If you're using Windows, check your `%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` file for any unwanted entries. Also consider posting the output of `ipconfig /all`.

Comment: I'm using Arch Linux. The internet problems happen on every device in my house, so if anything's infected, it's my router or my ISP. Seems unlikely though.

Comment: Do a hard reset of the router, if it is malware hopefully it is not persistent in the firmware and this will cure your issues, if it is permanent in the firmware, toss the router.

Comment: In the future please avoid using clickbait titles like this and try to give a brief summary of the issue you are experiencing.

Comment: Clickbait? It wasn't intentional, I legitimately think this is interesting AF. DNS of every site resolving to a perfect Swiss IP. Wew.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use Google DNS servers [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4] instead of ones assigned by ISP.
2. Set up Oetiker's SmokePing and run it as a service: http://oss.oetiker.ch/smokeping/.
3. When you configure SmokePing, give it an assortment of known IP addresses (internal and external) to ping.  It will make time series plots of ping response times, helping with diagnosis.
4. BTW, ping can't always be relied upon.  Some hosts block ICMP echo request/reply.

SmokePing is a free open source package for pinging several specified hosts at given time intervals and making RRD charts of their response latencies.  It is already in the repositories of most Linux distributions.

Pinging more than one host helps establish that the problem is with your connection and not the particular host that you are pinging.  The RRD charts make it easier to see if the connection is completely down, or just flagging in and out over the day.  I'd ping IP addresses instead of host names just to take DNS out of the equation.

As for Google DNS, I hate giving Google more information than I already do, but I have found their DNS servers to be the most reliable of the free ones.  I have seen all kinds of weirdness come out of ISP DNS servers.  I suspect this is because DNS seems so trivial at face value that people overlook all of the subtle ways it can be messed up.